# How to get a good staff

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to be able to find a strong staff to help me? Thanks and please share your ideas. I have tried searching dungeons and things but I have not found one strong enough. About 50-60 damage.

Comment: You are going to need to give us exactly what you mean by 'Good' or 'Strong Enough' for us to be able to answer your question.

Comment: 50-60 damage.....

Comment: Edit your question to put that and any other information in it :) Click the Edit button and have at it.. Tons of us have hundreds of hours in Skyrim, we can help you find something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staves that can deal 50+ damage are often rare and require a high-leveled character before they will appear as loot in chests or in the inventories of shops that would sell them (typically mage shops and general stores).

That said, [there are a few staves](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Staves_%28Skyrim%29#Destruction) that are not randomly generated, and they are typically held by [Dragon Priests](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Priest). There is a Staff of Icy Spear towards the end of the Dawnguard expanion's quests (In the [Inner Sanctum](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Inner_Sanctum)) on a frozen Falmer.

If you have the Dragonborn expansion, it is possible after a certain point to [enchant your own staves](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Staff_Enchanter). To do this you'd need the required materials, and have learned the spell (Icy Spear, Incinerate, Wall of [*element*]) that you wish the staff to be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all those staves are extremely rare and take a while to get, but you could always do the college of winterhold quests to get the staff of Magnus which is pretty good but you have to beat a dragon priest so for these staves you have to be a high level especially if you're playing on master or legendary.